# fetch 2nd row, 3rd row....200 row of a table in oracle by servlet

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp, servlets

I have a table named as abc in oracle and 4 records as follows:

```
   F         S        
  apple    mango 
  tiger    lion
  oak      banana
  pink     orange
```

### home.jsp

```
 <form action="NewServlet" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="count"  value="first" style="display:none;">
 <input type="submit" value="NEXT">
 </form>
```

### NewServlet.java

```
if(request.getParameter("count").equals("first")){// when i clicked on next button having value first

    rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY 'F','S' FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY"); 
    }// fetches apple and mango
    else{
rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY 'F','S' OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY");// when i clicked on next button having value second (in display.jsp)
        }// fetches tiger and lion

request.getRequestDispatcher("display.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

### display.jsp

```
<form action="NewServlet" method="post">
<input type="text" name="count"  value="second" style="display:none;">
<input type="submit" value="NEXT">
</form>

 String abc="", abc1=""
 abc= (String) request.getAttribute("fi");// prints apple 1st time and tiger 2nd time but 3rd and 4th record is not fetched
 abc1= (String) request.getAttribute("fi1");//prints mango 1st time and lion 2nd time but 3rd and 4th record is not fetched
```

How to fetch 3rd and 4th record and so on up to 100th row when I will keep clicking on NEXT button which is present in both `home.jsp` and `display.jsp`?

Comment: why -1 to this good question ????

Comment: what modification should i do in else block sql statement??

Comment: Can't you just substitute the `count` parameter into the offset of your second query?

Comment: ok trying but getting error sql statement not properly ended

Comment: Did you write something like this?
`...OFFSET " + getParameter("count").toString() + " ROWS..."`

Comment: Well tell me what you changed.
The query needs to change each time the `count` parameter changes. `getParameter()` is probably already a string to you don't even need the `toString()` part either.

Comment: And I can also see that you're not incrementing `count` at all.

Comment: ya i tried below answer but for count.match one error is coming cannot find symbol

Comment: His answer looks legit to me. Hard to debug without any real feedback from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `count` variable which gets passed as a request attribute.
For example:

NewServlet.java

```
String count = request.getParameter("count");
int c = 0;
String query;
if(count != null && count.matches("\\d+")){
    c = Integer.parseInt(count);
    query = "SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY 'F','S' OFFSET "+String.valueOf(c)+" ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY";
}else{
   query = "SELECT * FROM abc ORDER BY 'F','S' FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY";
}
request.setAttribute("count",++c);
```

display.jsp

```
<input type="text" name="count"  value="<%=(Integer)request.getAttribute("count")%>" style="display:none;">
```

home.jsp

```
 <form action="NewServlet" method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="NEXT">
 </form>
```

Remove the `count` input from `home.jsp` so that the first time you call the `servlet` the `count` parameter will be null.

Comment: Actually the offset needs to be one less than `count`, right?.

Comment: hey thnx Titus but after 1st row it displays 3rd row directly and after that nothing happens after clicking NEXT button

Comment: @shawnt00 i hv posted above please see

Comment: @shawnt00 I think you are right, I haven't used Oracle database in a while but I've just looked at the [doc](http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php) and it says the starting point will be `OFFSET + 1` but I'm not sure if the `OFFSET` can be 0

Comment: It's already split into two cases so the offset 0 won't happen.

Comment: @shawnt00 I've edited my answer, I'm still not sure it will work, I think that the first time `NEXT` is pressed in the `default.jsp` the `OFFSET` in the `query` will be 0.

Comment: Well just set c to 1 in the else block or initialize it that way.

Comment: now 2nd row printed !! but after that when i clicked next button that 2nd row is only getting printed , does not print 3rd record